# Is there a way to write this more concisely?

Tags: c

Is there a way to write the following code more concisely?

```
if ((count % 100 == 1) || (count % 100 == 21) || (count % 100 == 31)) return "рубль";
else if ((count % 100 == 41) || (count % 100 == 51) || (count % 100 == 61)) return "рубль";
else if ((count % 100 == 71) || (count % 100 == 81) || (count % 100 == 91)) return "рубль";
```

Comment: @Arkku — maybe `if (count % 10 == 1 && count % 100 != 11)`?  Or just `if (count % 10 == 1)` if the omission of 11 was accidental.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, you are right. Although I would guess that the exclusion of 11 is more likely to be an error in the question. (edit: This is in reference to my earlier suggestion `if ((count % 10) == 1 && (count % 11)) return "рубль";`, which I deleted since `count % 100 != 11` is not equal to `count % 11 != 0` for all values.)

Comment: Maybe make `count % 100` a variable first? You are, in worst case, doing `count % 100` 9 times.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for numbers with a decimal representation that ends with `1` (`count % 10 == 1`), except those with a decimal representation that ends with 11 (`count % 100 != 11`), so

```
if (count % 10 == 1 && count % 100 != 11)
   return "рубль";
```

---

Put differently,

```
if ((count % 100 == 1) || (count % 100 == 21) || (count % 100 == 31)) return "рубль";
else if ((count % 100 == 41) || (count % 100 == 51) || (count % 100 == 61)) return "рубль";
else if ((count % 100 == 71) || (count % 100 == 81) || (count % 100 == 91)) return "рубль";
```

is equivalent to

```
if (
   count % 100 ==  1 ||
// count % 100 == 11 ||   // Intentionally omitted.
   count % 100 == 21 ||
   count % 100 == 31 ||
   count % 100 == 41 ||
   count % 100 == 51 ||
   count % 100 == 61 ||
   count % 100 == 71 ||
   count % 100 == 81 ||
   count % 100 == 91
) {
   return "рубль";
}
```

This is already more readable, but we can do better.

If we could add `count % 100 == 11`, the condition would be more uniform, and that might open up avenues for simplification. So let's try that.

```
if (count % 100 != 11) {
   if (
      count % 100 ==  1 ||
      count % 100 == 11 ||
      count % 100 == 21 ||
      count % 100 == 31 ||
      count % 100 == 41 ||
      count % 100 == 51 ||
      count % 100 == 61 ||
      count % 100 == 71 ||
      count % 100 == 81 ||
      count % 100 == 91
   ) {
      return "рубль";
   }
}
```

Indeed, we can now simplify the large condition as follows:

```
if (count % 100 != 11) {
   if (count % 10 == 1) {
      return "рубль";
   }
}
```

Finally, you can collapse nested `if` statements by AND-ing their conditions.

```
if (count % 100 != 11 && count % 10 == 1)
   return "рубль";
```

More readable:

```
if (count % 10 == 1 && count % 100 != 11)
   return "рубль";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 91; i += 10)
    if (count % 100 == i)
        return "Please use english / Пожалуйста учи английский";
```

Comment: It is more compact, but hardly more efficient.  It also doesn't address explicitly the issue of 11 which is not covered in the question but is treated by your answer.